# Facing error 'Something went wrong Please try again or refresh the page' while adding OOTB custom list web part in Site Page in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, custom-list, sitepages, ootb

I have been facing below error when I try to add custom list web part in Site page in SharePoint online sub Site.

> Something went wrong Please try again or refresh the page.

[image]

Any idea about what causing this problem?

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue:

1. Create a page in the pages library and add the web part there, instead of creating the page in the site pages library.
2. Turn off **Require content approval for submitted items** on the pages library or in the library where you have your pages. This option will be available in the Library/List setting --> Versioning Settings.

If this answer helped you, then kindly mark it as answer, so that it will help others too in future.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thank you so much. @Karthik

Comment: @PravinDurgam If this answer helped you, then kindly upvote and mark it as answer, so that it will help others too in future.